# Erro ao tentar efetuar um POST no MongoDB com Insomnia

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, mongodb, mongoose

Olá, estou tentando inserir um dado no Banco de dados (MongoDB)utilizando o tipo POST, estou utilizando o Insomnia para efetuar os testes de insercao porem quando tento tenho um retorno de erros pelo terminal nodejs, como mostra abaixo:

> (node:13000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'split' of undefined
> at parseStringAsArray (C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Documents\Projetos\devMaps\backend\src\utils\parseStringAsArray.js:2:26)
> at store (C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Documents\Projetos\devMaps\backend\src\controllers\DevController.js:48:32)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:13000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:13000) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are  not handled will terminate
> the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Eu percebi que o erro ocorre pois informa que o split nao esta definido.

Segue os dois programas abaixo:

parseStringAsArray.js

```
module.exports = function parseStringAsArray(arrayAsString){
return arrayAsString.split(',').map(tech => tech.trim());
```

}

DevController.js

```html
const axios = require('axios');
const Dev = require("../models/Dev");
const parseStringAsArray = require('../utils/parseStringAsArray');

module.exports = {

    async index(request, response) {
        const devs = await Dev.find();
        return response.json(devs);

    },

    async store(request, response) {

        const { github_username, techs, latitude, longitude } = request.body;

        let dev = await Dev.findOne({ github_username });

        if(!dev) {

            const apiResponse = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${github_username}`);
    
            const { name = login, avatar_url, bio } = apiResponse.data;
    
            const techsArray = parseStringAsArray(techs);
            
            const location = {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
            };
    
            dev = await Dev.create({
                github_username,
                name,
                avatar_url,
                bio,
                techs: techsArray,
                location,
            });

        }
        
        return response.json(dev);
    }

};
```

E este eh o JSON que estou tentando inserir no MongoDB:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem poderia me ajudar por gentileza? Estou a mais de 2 dias tentando achar uma solucao mas ja nao sei mais o que fazer!

Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, o erro ocorre antes de gravar no Mongo, o motivo do erro é que ele não carregou "techs" do body do seu post Request.

Você pode confirmar isso exibindo no console o conteúdo do request body

```
async store(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body);
    const { github_username, techs, latitude, longitude } = request.body;
    console.log(github_username);
    console.log(techs);
    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);
}
```

Uma forma de evitar o problema seria verificar se "techs" foi recebido antes de executar a função "parseStringAsArray"

```
const techsArray = []
if (techs){
    techsArray = parseStringAsArray(techs);
}
```

Pode ser que o problema esteva no seu arquivo src/index.js, verifique se você ativou o middleware para receber dados por JSON antes de chamar as rotas.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Conteúdo do arquivo index:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');

const routes = require('./routes');
const { setupWebsocket } = require('./websocket')

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);

setupWebsocket(server);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://omnistack:omnistack@cluster0-kdxee.mongodb.net/week10?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);

server.listen(3333);
```

Comment: Bins, agradeco pela ajuda e irei validar todas as dicas que voce me passou e retorna pra dar o feedback.